# How to Retrieve related record value using SOQL?

Tags: soql, related-list

I'm using `Case` object and it has a look up of `Service_Technician__c`. Now i want to get the Service technician name which is related to a Case. How can i retrieve a service technician name using SOQL?
I tried like below:

```
sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Reason, Status, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Service_Technician__c WHERE id= '"+account.Assigned_To__c+"'),Service_Date__c FROM Case WHERE Status='New'",{
    onSuccess : layoutResults,
    onFailure : queryFailed,
    source : {
        output : document.getElementById("output"),
        startTime : new Date().getTime()
        }
});
```

Assigned_To__c is a look up name in Case Object

Comment: You could just put a formula field on the case to pull in the tech name

Comment: @Eric Tried using formula field. It's working as i expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing right now (i.e. using a sub-query) would work for querying child-relations. But in this case you're following a lookup and not querying a child-relation at all.

In the case of querying a lookup field, you can simply use the `__r` version of the fieldname to query fields from that relation. So in this case use `Assigned_To__r.Name` to query the Name of the Technician.

> SELECT Id, Assigned_To__r.Name FROM Case WHERE Status='New'

See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) for more information.

Comment: I am getting the following error.. 
SELECT Service_Technician__r.Name FROM 
       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Didn't understand relationship 'Service_Technician__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Then Service_Technician__c is not a lookup field. You said it is, right?

Comment: Assigned_To__c is a field in Case object, it is a look up of Service_Technician__c

Comment: Got it. It should be Assigned_To__r.Name

Comment: Ah ok, so the lookup field is Assigned_To__c and it references the Service_Technician__c object. I've updated my answer to reflect that! If it worked, please accept this answer or if it didn't: write your own and accept that one :-)